# Cell Fracture Crack it Addon Blender 2.9

Tags: add-on, cell-fracture

I was following this tutorial by Tutor4U on Youtube that explains how to make a Text covered with mud being washed with water. He was using Blender 2.79 in the tutorial to generate the mud, I checked the cell fracture crack it addon in blender 2.92 but I couldn't find it. Any suggestions are welcome.

Blender 2.79 Cell Fracture crackit addon
[image: Blender 2.79 Cell Fracture crackit addon]

Blender 2.9 Cell Fracture crackit addon not present
[image: Blender 2.9 Cell Fracture crackit addon not present]

Comment: In 2.92 the crack-it add on has been merged into Cell Fracture so you should be able to follow the tutorial after enabling Cell Fracture.

Comment: But how do I add the mud

Comment: Check this tutorial to know what I mean https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q0_koJLc0Og

Answer (score 1):

do you mean this?

[image]

Go to Edit -> Preferences -> Add-ons -> type cell in search field and check the white box.

Comment: No I mean, The previous Cell Fracure Crack it addon that was previously in Blender 2.79 is not available in Blender 2.9. Check the Tutorial below to see what I mean.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q0_koJLc0Og

Comment: would have been better if you had that more detailed description, which you have now, had been already in your first post version....so i had not to waste my time.